# Table- Javascript and math in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML5 and CSS3.

1)I would like some help figuring out tables. I would like the user to input values (info1, info2, info3) into the table columns. Then use those values on button "click" to generate an answer (Answer) in the Answer column.

2)Also, how do you restrict the input values to numeric values only? I tried using input type = "number" but get the little arrows to increment the value, but I can still enter letters.

Thanks
CzY Horse

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Table</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    function sayHi(){
        var info1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("info1").value) ;
        var info2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("info2").value) ;
        var info3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("info3").value) ;

        var Answer = document.getElementById("Answer");
        answer.value = info1.value + info2.value * info3.value /100 ;
    } // end sayHi

</script>    
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Row 1</th>
        <th>Row 2</th>
        <th>Row 3</th>
        <th>Answer</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type = "text"
            id = "info1">
        </td>
        <td><input type = "text"
            id = "info2">
        </td>
        <td><input type = "text"
            id = "info3">
        </td>
        <td><input type = "text"
            id = "Answer" READONLY>
        </td>

    </tr>





   </table>
<section>
            <input type = "button"
            value = "Calculate"
            onClick = "javascript:sayHi()"/>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see how CSS, CSS3, nor HTML5 figure into this question at all.

Comment: If you use onClick, there's no need to add `javascript:`. This is only required when using a link (`<a href="javascript:...">`)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking whether the parsed number is NaN or not. If so, the user entered something that couldn't be parsed to a number.

```
if (isNaN(info1) || isNaN(info2) || isNaN(info3)) {
    alert('Only numbers!');
    return false;
}
```

Plus, because you already parsed the values of the text fields to a number, you don't need to add `.value` when using the variables in JavaScript

```
Answer.value = info1 + info2...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this oneliner to create a calculated value:

```
( [].slice.call( 
   document.querySelectorAll('table td input[type=text]:not([disabled])'))
    .map( function (a) { return +(a.value) || 0; })
    .reverse()
    .reduce( function (a,b,i) {return i<2 ? a*b : a+b;} ) ) / 100
```

With it, the input-values are automatically checked (`+a.value || 0`): if not numeric, the default value 0 is used.

A demo in [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/3c2waoov/)

See [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (`Array.map`) and [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (`Array.reduce`)

Answer (score 0):

You have various mistakes and bugs in your code, too many to list but here is a fiddle try it out and you can see your fixed code working

http://jsfiddle.net/bz7hknhk/

```
sayHi = function () {
 var info1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("info1").value);
 var info2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("info2").value);
 var info3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("info3").value);

 var Answer = document.getElementById("Answer");
 Answer.value = info1 + info2 * info3 / 100;
} // end sayHi
```

Comment: I should point out this makes the sayHi() function work, and does your calculation, whether the math result is correct I can't say, but I would think from here you can move forward.